# Can you publish a message to an SNS topic using an AWS Lambda function backed by node.js?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

Can you publish a message to an SNS topic using an AWS Lambda function backed by node.js?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Yes, you could write a Lambda function that publishes to an SNS topic.  The code running in Lambda has access to the full AWS SDK for [Java](http://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/) or [Javascript](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/index.html), whichever your function is using.  You just need to make sure you give the IAM role executing the function access to publish to your topic.  In Javascript:

```
console.log("Loading function");
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var eventText = JSON.stringify(event, null, 2);
    console.log("Received event:", eventText);
    var sns = new AWS.SNS();
    var params = {
        Message: eventText, 
        Subject: "Test SNS From Lambda",
        TopicArn: "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:test-topic1"
    };
    sns.publish(params, context.done);
};
```

It is also possible to handle SNS messages using Lambda functions.  You might take a look at the `sns-message` function blueprint, offered through the **Create a Lambda function** button on the Lambda console.

Comment: I am using Python, and I am trying to send a notification to `TargetArn`, but, I am getting an exception that the Lambda function does not have the permission to call SNS notification. Is this only possible with `TopicArn` or can we send Notification to indivial Endpoints using AWS LAmbda?

Comment: I have not tried it, but I believe you can send to particular endpoint if you have the EndpointArn from [create_platform_endpoint()](https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.create_platform_endpoint), then call [publish()](https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.publish) passing the EndpointArn in the TopicArn field.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I had the endpoint ARN, but my lambda function did not have permission to access SNS, then I found out that all I had to do was give him the access in The lambda function's role using amazon's IAM as mentioned in the first half of @kixorz answer. Then it worked fine.

Comment: @James is it possible to read and update existing topic's message data from node js ??

Comment: @redblood, SNS Topics themselves are write-only.  But you can subscribe a Lambda function to listen to the topic, then process messages sent to it.  I recommend not using the same Lambda function to both write and subscribe to a topic, for fear of an endless loop.

Answer (score 65):

First, you need to grant your `Lambda IAM role` permissions to publish to your `SNS topic` using proper `IAM policy`.

```
{
    "Action" : [
        "sns:Publish",
        "sns:Subscribe"
    ],
    "Effect" : "Allow",
    "Resource" : [
        { "Ref" : "<your SNS topic ARN>" }
    ]
}
```

Then you can use following code to `SNS publish` to your `SNS topic` from your other `Lambda` or `Node.js` code.

```
var message = {};
var sns = new AWS.SNS();
sns.publish({
    TopicArn: "<your SNS topic ARN>",
    Message: JSON.stringify(message)
}, function(err, data) {
    if(err) {
        console.error('error publishing to SNS');
        context.fail(err);
    } else {
        console.info('message published to SNS');
        context.succeed(null, data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why do you think you need the "sns:Subscribe" in your role?

Comment: Well, I'm not a fan of too many restrictions. This allows me to use the same policy for both publishers and subscribers. In this particular case you're fine with just `sns:Publish`.

Comment: needed to switch `.done` to `.succeed` but worked for me

Comment: Good on ya for mentioning the need for a policy, I was wondering what I did wrong.

Comment: For my case, I would like to Only configure the Topic Arn value in IAM AWS permissions' policy JSON.  I do Not want to reference the Topic Arn in the application's code.  How can   it be done? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user1338998 The Topic ARN is required for the Publish method. You may want to store the ARN in the application configuration, environment variable or a parameter store and read it when the app is starting.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the policy. If you want to allow any resource in your account to use the policy, modify the resource to just `"Resource": "arn:aws:sns:*:your-account-id:*"`

Answer (score 2):

To send the SNS response into lambda use this:

```
await sns.publish({
    Message: snsPayload,
    MessageStructure: 'json',
    TargetArn: endPointArn}).promise()
```

(Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54326616/8459761))