# Can you send SNS push notification from lambda function in Amazon AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-lambda

I am developing an application with Amazon AWS and what I am trying to achieve is to attach a lambda function to DynamoDB table, so after a new row is added ,the lambda function is triggered.
In the above mentioned lambda function I want to add the functionality to send a push notification with Amazon SNS service, but I could not find any information in their documentation if that is possible and if it is, what exactly needs to be done to get it working? What I found in their documentation is that you can attach lambda function trigger to a SNS topic, which means that after a notification is pushed then the function is called, but what I am interested in is to send a push notification directly from lambda function. I would appreciate if someone shed some light on this topic for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you publish a message to an SNS topic using an AWS Lambda function backed by node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31484868/can-you-publish-a-message-to-an-sns-topic-using-an-aws-lambda-function-backed-by)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can call any of the API functions from Lambda. Perhaps if you posted some code and the errors you are getting you could get more specific help.

Comment: That is great! I have not written any code yet, I just wanted to know if it is possible. I got confused, because I found examples for every other service in the documentation except sending pushes with Lambda. There is only a small amount of documentation in the case where you add a trigger to catch a sent push notification. Could you please link me to some source of information for the feature I seek?