# AWS Lambda to run in background even after sending response to API Gateway

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have searched all through the net but didn't find a solution of how to make this functionality get succeeded. Require help.

My requirement is: I want a that if I trigger an aws lambda function written in node.js and uses an aws-serverless-express module must send back response quickly to API gateway but still should not exit and still run in the backend and we could see cloud watch logs. It must be asynchronous.

The code snippet is:

```
    app.get('/check', function(req, res){
     method.invoke(req)
     res.status(200).send('success')
   })
```

I did and checked like this but the lambda function gets stopped and returns the response to api gateway it didn't even runs the method.invoke() function in backend.

Please correct me if anything I am understanding or doing wrong. I checked with this link: [Invoke AWS Lambda and return response to API Gateway asyncronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41102337/invoke-aws-lambda-and-return-response-to-api-gateway-asyncronously)

Is it the only way to do this problem. Creating two lambda functions.

Answer (score 12):

You can achieve this by using [AWS Lambda Step functions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/welcome.html), connected to API Gateway, having parallel execution of branches with two lambda functions, where one returns a response to API Gateway and other executes asynchronously.

Comment: Any chance you could post an image of what this would look like (to achieve the effect of returning a response to API Gateway)?

Comment: I'm also dying to know how you can customize the response that API Gateway returns from a Step Function.

Answer (score 5):

Can't find a link to the documentation of AWS, but normally it is not possible to continue processing after the Lambda function has returned the response. That's just not how the [available runtimes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html) (for the different programming languages) are constructed.

Next to invoking separate asynchronous processes (e.g., other Lambda function requests, or putting work on a queue) or using [AWS Step functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/welcome.html) as mentioned here, there's a third method that I know that works: supply a special [custom runtime](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-custom.html) for the AWS Lambda functions that addresses this need.

Next to the standard runtimes, you can [create and specify a custom runtime](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-custom.html#runtimes-custom-build) to be used for your AWS Lambda functions. In the standard runtimes, the response of your handler is being posted to the Lambda execution context, after which no activities are possible in your handler because the handler is being terminated (or at least: paused).

So, the trick to make additional processing possible *after sending the response* is to move the responsibility of posting the response to the Lambda operating content from the bootstrap script to the Lambda function handler itself... and continue to do your processing in your Lambda function handler after already having sent the response. Using your custom runtime, processing in the Lambda functions will then not be terminated after having sent the response, since it's not how your custom runtime is constructed.

It's not the architecturally-best solution, as it messes with the responsibilities between the Lambda operating context and your Lambda functions handlers... but it makes it possible to do processing in your Lambda function handlers after having sent the response.

Comment: My colleague just published a blog post about this solution, as we were facing this problem in a piece of software we built. See https://xebia.com/blog/how-to-reduce-aws-lambda-latency-using-custom-runtimes/. Our case was that we needed to duplicate all requests to a function to a couple of other functions, and collect and compare the responses... but didn't want to wait with sending the response out of the first function.

Answer (score 3):

Besides Step Functions, you could just invoke another Lambda function using the SDK built-in to the Lambda environment.

I'm no expert in express or NodeJS but I would also think there should be a way to send the HTTP response back and still continue code execution.

Comment: If you don't return from the code, just send the response ( res.send() ), the code will continue executing. However, this is not true for Lambda. I am having the same issue that on my machine, it works perfectly. But deployed on Lambda the code stops executing after sending the HTTP response back to client.

Answer (score 2):

Step function seems the best solution here. See @Ashan's reply. Apart from that you can use the new invoke method in lambda nodejs sdk. Note that invokeAsync is now deprecated. You can set InvocationType to Event See the example below. which is taken from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property)

```
var params = {
  ClientContext: "MyApp", 
  FunctionName: "MyFunction", 
  InvocationType: "Event", 
  LogType: "Tail", 
  Payload: <Binary String>, 
  Qualifier: "1"
 };
 lambda.invoke(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);           // successful response
   /*
   data = {
    FunctionError: "", 
    LogResult: "", 
    Payload: <Binary String>, 
    StatusCode: 123
   }
   */
 });
```

one example use case is, first function would return an immediate response, and it would trigger another lambda function which would execute the tasks and eventually may be call a webhook.

Answer (score -1):

I am just new here and I want to help so here is how I overcame this problem:
I did install axios in my javascript code and then did a request on the other function
I just added an http api endpoint via serverless and viola stuff was fixed plus I can pass parameters in the request body.

The other's call it fire and forget request. You should look into it ;)