# Can you publish multiple messages to an SNS topic using an AWS Lambda function backed by node.js 8.10?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

There is a related question regarding how to publish s single message:  [Can you publish a message to an SNS topic using an AWS Lambda function backed by node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31484868/)

However, my question is related to publish more than one message.
I am using node 8.10 and my handler is asynchronous.

Comment: Did you try it and have an issue?

Comment: yes, I works without async+await and when I make the handler async it fails

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) feature to encapsulate multiple calls to sns.publish.

1. Create a one-notification-publish function that returns Promise:

.

```
function onePublishPromise(notificationParams){ 
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    sns.publish(notificationParams, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Unable to send notification message. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            reject(err);
        } else {
            console.log("Results from sending notification message: ", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
            resolve(null);
        }
    });
  });
}
```

2. Create and send notifications in parallel:

`// Create notifications params
const notifications = [
    {`

```
    Subject: 'A new notification',
    Message: 'Some message',
    TopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:us-west-1:000000000:SomeTopic'

   }
   // , ...
];
// Send all notifications
const notificationsDelivery = notifications.map(onePublishPromise);
// Wait for delivery results
Promise.all(notificationsDelivery).then(callback).catch(callback);
```

`callback` will be called after all messages published (successfully or not)

Answer (score 0):

The related question uses `context.done`, which would end the lambda before making a second call. Using

```
sns.publish(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

you can make more calls, e.g.

```
sns.publish(params2, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Whether you want to use `async.waterfall`, nest the calls or let them go asynchronously is up to you.